# Start runnable jar with process builder

Tags: java, processbuilder

How to write this command in process builder. I tried different combinations, but nothing worked for me.

```
/Users/rawfodog/Documents/OpenJRE11/Contents/Home/bin/Java -jar --module-path /Users/rawfodog/Downloads/AllLibrary --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml /Users/rawfodog/Downloads/app.jar
```

**EDIT**

My code:

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/rawfodog/Documents/OpenJRE11/Contents/Home/bin/Java", "-jar", "--module-path /Users/rawfodog/Downloads/AllLibrary","--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml", "/Users/rawfodog/Downloads/app.jar");
        pb.start();
```

Comment: It will help if you show what you have tried, with details of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate each of the individual parameters - currently 2 arguments are joined in the "--module-path" argument:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
  "/Users/rawfodog/Documents/OpenJRE11/Contents/Home/bin/Java"
   , "-jar"
   , "--module-path"
   , "/Users/rawfodog/Downloads/AllLibrary"
   ,"--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
   , "/Users/rawfodog/Downloads/app.jar");
```

Also add code to check the exit status / wait for end of process:

```
Process p = pb.start();
int rc = p.waitFor();
```